Unable to clean a string column with pyspark
I'm currently connecting to an ibm db2 database, reading a table into a pyspark dataframe and writing it into hdfs as parquet. Out of around 200 tables around 10% are throwing out the same error:

ERROR Utils: Aborting task com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException
[jcc][t4][1065][12306][4.31.10] Caught
java.io.CharConversionException. See attached Throwable for details.
ERRORCODE=-4220, SQLSTATE=null.

df = spark.read.format("jdbc") \
          .option("url", db2_url) \
          .option("driver", "com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver") \
          .option("dbtable", db_table) \
          .option("user", db2_user) \
          .option("password", db2_password) \
          .option("charset", "UTF-8") \
          .load()
df_cleaned = df.withColumn("USER_ID", regexp_replace("USER_ID", "[^a-zA-Z0-9]", ""))

df_cleaned.write.mode("append").option("maxRecordsPerFile", 5000000).parquet(hdfs_path)

During my testing of one table I found that the column causing the issue was 'USER_ID' of type character(8) however my attempts to force it to be utf-8 by removing any non digit/letter characters still threw the same error.
I know its this column because when I drop it, it writes successfully.
Using the below query when reading also worked:
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(USER_ID, '[^\\x20-\\x7E]', '') AS CLEAN_USER_ID, * 

But I don't want to hard code this for all the 20+ tables, I'd much rather prefer to clean the data using Spark if possible.
Am I just cleaning data wrong in PySpark?

[^a-zA-Z0-9] I believe that will match only the FIRST non-digit/letter, not ALL such characters.

@JohnGordon Tested out the regex on regex101 and it catches all characters
